# Edit a variable value in the location returned from dbghelp.dll in the exe C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to edit the value of an integer in the exe? I am getting the location/address of the variable using dbghelp.dll. So is possible to change the value of the variable by editing the content of  this address?
The reason for this requirement is, I can't figure out the value of the variable in the earlier stages of coding. I would like to patch it in the exe along with the release build.

Comment: Provided it is a static storage variable (global or global static), its initialization value is directly stored in the exe file and can be changed. If you have never done that before, you should build a tiny program with a global variable and test there that it works.

Comment: I don't see how patching it into a binary would be easier than rebuilding it (or storing the value as a runtime setting in an external config file). One other point to consider is that edits to the EXE change any prior hashes/checksums and invalidate any digital signatures embedded into the binary.

Comment: @SergeBallesta- I am new to this. One doubt I have is, the location which is returned from dbghelp.dll is from .text segment or .data segment? As variables are stored in .data segment. I tried to edit the particular location, but it is giving exception.                  .

Comment: @dxiv - I can't take the option of config file as it should be less accessible for others.

Comment: @AcCoder You could always encrypt/obfuscate the setting in the external file. Writing it into the EXE doesn't hide it a lot better, anyway.

Comment: @dxiv - I got the point. But I don't have any other choice than patching the exe. Is there any other way to locate a variable in the exe and patch it? I checked about the string table resource. I think that can be editable in the exe. Please suggest if any good methods for doing this.